# JPA: don't update specific fields using random function

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is there anyway, don't update specific fields which are randomly generated using `@DynamicUpdate`

For example, i have jpa entity like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "Classes")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@ToString
@DynamicUpdate
public class Classes {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ClassId")
    private Long classId;

    @Column(name = "CourseSourceId")
    private String courseSourceId;
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "Grades",updatable = false)
    private String grades;
    @Column(name = "CourseId")
    private String courseId;
    @Column(name = "ClassCode",updatable = false)
    private String classCode;
    @Column(name = "Subjects")
    private String subjects;
    @Column(name = "SubjectCodes")
    private String subjectCodes;
    @Column(name = "Periods")
    private String periods;
    @Column(name = "StaffSectionCode",updatable = false)
    private String staffSectionCode;
    @Column(name = "StudentSectionCode",updatable = false)
    private String studentSectionCode;
    
}
```

When i use `(updatable=false)` on grades column it's not updated, but `StaffSectionCode` and `studentSectionCode` are getting updated because i am using `math.random` function.

Here is my controller class, i am handling both post and put functionality in a same class.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/addClasses")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('Write')")
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveCLasses(@Valid @RequestBody AddClassesCommand command, @RequestHeader(ClassesConstants.AUTHORIZATION) String token) {
    try {
        log.info("saveCLasses {} Service Calling...");
        Long id = UniqueIdentifierGenerate.get64MostSignificantBitsForVersion1();
        command.setId(id);
        Date date = new Date();
        Long time = date.getTime() + (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        command.getClasses().setStaffAccessCode(ApplicationConstants.STAFF_SECTION_CODE + time);
        Long std = date.getTime() + (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        command.getClasses().setStudentAccessCode(ApplicationConstants.STUDENT_SECTION_CODE + std);
        command.setUctx(TokenConversion.getUserContextJson(token));
        commandGateway.sendAndWait(command);
        command.setUctx(null);
        log.info("saveClasses {} Service Complete successfully...");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new CreatedResponse(id, ClassesConstants.getSuccessMessage
                (ClassesConstants.CLASSES, ClassesConstants.CREATE), command, true), HttpStatus.CREATED);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info(e.getMessage());
        var safeErrorMessage = ClassesConstants.CREATE_ERROR_MSG;
        return new ResponseEntity<>(safeErrorMessage, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Here is my `@eventHandler` class where i am hanlding update functionality.

```
private Classes saveClasses(AddClassesEvent event, ActiveSessionInfo activeSessionInfo) {
    try {
        log.info("saveClasses {} calling...");
/**
 if (event.getClasses().getClassId() != null) {
                guid = event.getClasses().getClassId();
            } else {
                guid = event.getId().toString();
            }

        var existingId = classesRepository.findByGuid(guid);
        if (existingId != null) {
            cls = existingId;
        } else {
            cls.setGuid(event.getId().toString());
            cls.setClassId(classesRepository.findNextValFromClasses_Seq()+100);
            classesHelper.updateSeqValueInDb(ApplicationConstants.DEFAULT_CLASSES_SEQUENCE, cls.getClassId(), 1l);
        }
**/ between this function i want to update fields and in else case i want to create fields data.

        cls.setName(event.getClasses().getClassName());
        cls.setOrgId(event.getClasses().getOrgId());
        if (activeSessionInfo != null && activeSessionInfo.getYearId() != null) {
            cls.setSchoolYearId(activeSessionInfo.getYearId());
        }
        cls.setPeriods(event.getClasses().getPeriod());
        cls.setCourseId(event.getClasses().getCourseId());
        if (activeSessionInfo != null && activeSessionInfo.getTenantId() != null) {
            cls.setTenantId(activeSessionInfo.getTenantId());
        }
        cls.setStaffSectionCode(event.getClasses().getStaffAccessCode());
        cls.setStudentSectionCode(event.getClasses().getStudentAccessCode());
   
        classesRepository.saveAndFlush(cls);
        saveCoTeacherEnrollmentDetails(event, cls.getClassId(), activeSessionInfo);
        log.info("saveClasses {} calling end...");

        return cls;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure StaffSectionCode and studentSectionCode are getting updated to db, it might be in jpa cache. please use entityManager.clear() then do get the row details.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it's still getting updated even i used entityManager.clear().

Comment: Is there any way to restrict staffSectionCode and studentSectionCode on controller level, so that in update case use the same classid which is basically a guid.

Comment: just try to print the query or use jpa logger that will show which query is getting fired. as per doc if annotation is at field level that it should not part of the update statement.

Comment: can you just give me little code demo how to handle this case.